# Quaternion issues

Tags: arduino, quaternions, euler-angles, mpu

I'm working with a MPU9250 to control a 3D position. I have an object that can rotate in 3 axis ( Roll, Pitch and Yaw) but I found some problems.
Initially I tried to calculate Euler Angles from Quaternions, but I discover that Euler Angles have 2 discontinuity in +/- 90 degrees, and so if I rotate the MPU for 365 deg it gives me wrong values like it's shifting while rotating.
I read that there is the possibility to convert Quaternions to DCM (Direction Cosine Matrix) but I find this algorithm fills too much the Arduino processor for calculations.

The last possibility that comes to my mind is to control the position directly with Quaternions, so I have to "forecast" the arriving Quaternion to stop the rotation when the MPU will give me the same Quaternion.

If anyone knows how to implement this or any other way please let me know your suggestions.

Many thanks,
Luca

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not entirely clear from your question what you are trying to achieve. Could you please describe what is the desired output? Also, what you mean by "stopping the rotation" when the MPU returns the same Quaternion? (same to what?)